# Ruby temperature converter using user input in a method

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a temperature converter from Farenheit to Celcius using a method that:
Get's input from the user -> makes the calculation -> delivers the output of the calculation.

I have managed to do this using a variables, but I want to do it using a method.

```
  puts "Enter degrees in Celcius: "
  inputCelsius = gets.to_f
  conversion = (inputCelsius * 9) / 5 + 32
  puts conversion
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps like this?

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius)
  (celsius.to_f * 9) / 5 + 32
end

puts 'Enter degrees in Celcius:'
puts celsius_to_fahrenheit(gets)
```

Explanation: `def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius)` defines a method with the name `celsius_to_fahrenheit` that accepts one parameter. The parameter will be stored in a local variable named `celsius`.

In the next line the value of the variable `celsius` - that was passed to the method - is used for the calculation.

Comment: @Adi : Please find an explanation in my updated answer.